# Is a closed set minus its limit points open?

Tags: real-analysis

If I have a set $A$ that is closed and $A'$ that contains all of its limit points, is $A \setminus A'$ open?

I'm trying to use this to show that $A'$ is closed.

Comment: In general this is not true. Are you trying to prove that the set comprised of the limit points of A is closed, or that $\overline{A}$ (A closure) is closed?

Comment: Note that $A\subseteq A'$ since any $x\in A$ is of course also a limit point in $A$ (take the constant sequence $(x,x,x,\ldots)$). Hence, $A\setminus A'$ does not really make sense. Do you mean $A'\setminus A$?

Comment: To clarify, is A' referring to A closure? or is A' just the set of limit points?

Comment: I'm trying to show that the set of all limit points of A is closed if A is closed.  I thought that an open set contains none of it's limit points, I wasn't sure whether or not a set containing none of it's limit points was open.  Thinking more about it, it's pretty clear that this isn't so.

Comment: An open set contains a neighborhood of every point in it.  It contains many of its limit points, but not necessarily all of them.  All the points in $(0,1)$ are limit points of $(0,1)$, but so are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: $A\setminus A'$ is closed **in the relative topology** of $A$, from which it follows that $A'$ is closed in the relative topology of $A$. Since a (relatively) closed subset of a closed set is closed, it follows that $A'$ is closed in the original space.

Answer (score 6):

No. Consider the union

$$S = [0,1]\cup\{2\}$$

where $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Notice that $S$ is closed: it contains all its limit points (and then some). All points in $[0,1]$ are limit points of $S$, but $2$ is not a limit point (it is an isolated point) in $S$.

Now, $S$ minus its limit points, $S\setminus [0,1] = \{2\}$, is **not an open set**. To see why, given any $\varepsilon$, there does not exist any neighborhood $(2-\varepsilon, 2+\varepsilon)$ surrounding the point $2$ that is completely contained within the set $\{2\}$.

In fact, $\{2\}$ is a non-open, closed set that can also be represented as the closed interval $[2,2]$.

---

Now, it is *not always* true that a set $A$ less the set of its limit points $A^\prime$ is necessarily non-open. Take the set of real numbers, for example. In this case, $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{R}^\prime$ is the empty set $\varnothing$, which is open. ($\mathbb{R}^\prime = \mathbb{R}$ because every point in $\mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{R}$.)

However, it *is always* true that a set $A$ less the set of its limit points $A^\prime$ is necessarily closed. Prove this for extra credit.

Answer (score 1):

if $A$ is $T_1$ space, then $A'$ is closed.  In fact, we just have to show that $A''\subset A'$.

For any $x\in A''$, for any neighborhood $U$ of $x$ we have that $U\cap (A'-\{x\})\neq \emptyset$. So we can choose $y\in A'-\{x\}$ such that $y\in U$. Since $A$　is $T_1$ space, we can find a neighborhood $V$ of $y$ such that $x\not\in V$. So $x\not\in U\cap V$ and $U\cap V$ is a neighborhood of $y$.

Then  $(U\cap V)\cap (A-\{y\})\neq \emptyset$, and $U\cap(A-\{x\})\supset V\cap U\cap (A-\{x\})\neq \emptyset$. This implies that $x\in A'$.

Answer (score 1):

No, this would not be true.

If the set was finite then it would contain no limit points. But, the limit points would be the null set. And we know that the null set is a subset of the finite subset. So, our set contains all none of the limit points and we see that it is closed. So we have a closed finite subset with null limit points.

Answer (score 0):

No! Take $A=\overline{\mathscr{O}}\cup \mathscr{F}$, where $\mathscr{O}$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\mathscr{F}$ a (non-empty) finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\overline{\mathscr{O}}\cap \mathscr{F}=\emptyset$. Then 
$$
A\setminus A'=(\overline{\mathscr{O}}\cup \mathscr{F})\setminus\mathscr{O}'=(\overline{\mathscr{O}}\setminus \mathscr{O}')\cup\mathscr{F}
$$
is not open because $\mathscr{F}$ is closed and $(\overline{\mathscr{O}}\setminus \mathscr{O}')\cap\mathscr{F}=\emptyset$.